# Entity-Framework 6 Add Migration trying to migrate wrong project

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to add a migrations because I made some changes to my model. 
I have an inventory items class that I took a few POCOs from and add them to the parent Parts class. All of my data model is in a project called `IS.DataModel`. This project also includes my migrations folder.

After making the changes, I tried to `add-migration 'Second'` and it told me that i needed to add entity framework to a different project called `IS.Import`. Being that project does have a reference to `Is.DataModel` I added entity framework.

Next, i ran add-migration again and it told me that I needed to enable migrations on Is.Import. I tried to do so and it told me there is not a context found.

I started searching for some answers on this and found [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) which helped explain the concept of migrations a little more, but I still do not understand what I am doing wrong and why it is trying to migrate from wrong project.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it was trying to migrate a project that didn't have a context. What I ended up doing was changing `add-migration 'Second'` to `add-migration -ProjectName Is.DataModel 'Second`.

And finaly updating database like: `Update-Database -ProjectName Is.DataModel -verbose`